# How to preserve `backticks` in R's quote() even though not needed?

Tags: r, data.table

Knowing that some characters such as `-` (hyphen) or  (space) should not be used in regular R names, I need to use them in a specific scenario.

The following is a minimal reproducible example to illustrate the question.

Given the following table

```
library(data.table)

dat <- data.table(x = 1:8, 
                  y = rep(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 2), 2), 
                  `y-z` = rep(c("c", "d"), each = 4))
```

I am able to do the following.

```
dat[, sum(x), by = y]     # works
dat[, sum(x), by = `y`]   # works
dat[, sum(x), by = `y-z`] # works

dat[, sum(x), by = eval("`y`, `y-z`", envir = .SD)] # works
```

Now consider that I want to specify some queries either in a list or plain (does not matter).

```
arg1 <- quote(`y`)
arg2 <- quote(`y-z`)

arg_list <- list(arg1 = quote(`y`), 
                 arg2 = quote(`y-z`), 
                 arg3 = quote(`y` == "a"), 
                 arg4 = quote(`y-z` == "d"))
```

I am able to do the following *only* if my argument *needs* backquotes and has not been parsed/deparsed beforhand in `quote()`.

```
# simple cases
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(arg1, envir = .SD)] # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(arg2, envir = .SD)] # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(arg_list[["arg1"]], envir = .SD)] # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(arg_list[["arg2"]], envir = .SD)] # works

# complex cases in which "by" is constructed
dat[, sum(x), by = .(`y`, `y-z`)] # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval("`y`, `y-z`", envir = .SD)] # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(paste(c("`y`,", "sub =", "`y-z`"), collapse = ""), envir = .SD)] # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(paste(c("`y`,", "sub =", arg2), collapse = ""), envir = .SD)]    # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(paste(c("`y`,", "sub =", "`y`"), collapse = ""), envir = .SD)]   # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(paste(c("`y`,", "sub =", arg1), collapse = ""), envir = .SD)]    # fails

dat[, sum(x), by = eval(paste(c("`y`,", "sub =", arg_list[["arg2"]]), collapse = ""), envir = .SD)] # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(paste(c("`y`,", "sub =", arg_list[["arg1"]]), collapse = ""), envir = .SD)] # fails

# probably even more complex cases
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(paste(c("`y`, sub = `y-z` == 'd'"), collapse = ""), envir = .SD)] # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(paste(c("`y`,", "sub =", arg_list[["arg4"]]), collapse = ""), envir = .SD)] # works
dat[, sum(x), by = eval(paste(c("`y`,", "sub =", arg_list[["arg3"]]), collapse = ""), envir = .SD)] # fails
```

I am aware that the backticks have disappeared when I check the output of `arg1` and `arg_list[["arg1"]]` or `arg_list[["arg4"]]`. But apparently, I would need them to construct the proper query in `data.table`'s `by =` argument.

Is there a way to make all cases work out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `eval` at the end, which may prove simpler. For example,

```
> ex = substitute(dat[, sum(x), by=myby], list(myby = quote(list(y, `y-z`))))
> eval(ex)
   y y-z V1
1: a   c  3
2: b   c  7
3: a   d 11
4: b   d 15
```

Then your problem is how to build the expression `` quote(list(y, `y-z`)) ``, which is a base R problem that doesn't require detailed knowledge of what `DT[, ..., by=eval(...)]` does internally.

With the OP's objects, here's one way, using `call`:

```
myby = with(arg_list, call("list", arg1, arg2))
ex = substitute(dat[, sum(x), by=myby], list(myby = myby) )
eval(ex)
```

From the OP's comment, you can also name the arguments in `call(...)`:

> In case someone is looking for named arguments in data.table, one can simply use an unquoted expression `myby = with(arg_list, call("list", arg1, sub = arg3))`. – ninjaminb

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! :) In case someone is looking for named arguments in `data.table`, one can simply use an unquoted expression `myby = with(arg_list, call("list", arg1, sub = arg3))`.

Comment: @ninjaminb Cool, glad it works :) I didn't know that re named args -- I've added it to the answer.